# Uninstalling Netbeans 8.2 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, jdk, netbeans

When I try to run `uninstall.sh` (Netbeans) it says: Unsupported JVM version at `/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_144`

But what I did before:

1. downloaded jdk 10.0.1
2. stored it in `/usr/local/java`
3. updated `/usr/profile` with `JAVA_HOME && PATH`
4. ran `update-alternatives --install` && `--set` for java, javac, javaws
5. ran source `/usr/profile`
6. couldn't create new project/new file in netbeans and realized there are some issues between netbeans 8.2 and jdk 9 && 10.
7. ran `update-alternatives --remove-all` java, javac, javaws
8. deleted `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`
9. deleted `/usr/local/java`
10. downloaded jdk 8
11. stored it in `/usr/lib/java`
12. updated `/etc/environment` with `JAVA_HOME` && `PATH`
13. updated `~/.bashrc` with JAVA_HOME && PATH
14. ran `updated-alternatives --install` && `--set` for java, javac, javaws
15. ran source `/etc/environment`
16. ran source `~/.bashrc`

Thanks in advance,